# figcaption se "desborda"

Tags: css

me pasa esto con mi imagen. El figcaption se "desborda", al desplegarlo en tamaño 760 px.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé por qué. He puesto que figcaption tenga position absolute y figure, relative, estando figcaption dentro de figure como debería ser y overflow hidden.

```css
#web figure {

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}

figure:hover figcaption {
 -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
 top: 0;
}

figcaption {
 -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
 -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
 -o-transition-delay: .2s;
 -ms-transition-delay: .2s;
 transition-delay: .2s;
 overflow: hidden;

}



figcaption h6 {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: white;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 position: relative;
 right: 100%;
 margin-top: 37px;
 font-size: 2em;
 
}

figcaption p {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 20px;
 position: relative;
 left: 100%;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

figure:hover h6,figure:hover p {
 left: 0;
} 

figcaption a {
 color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 padding: 4px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

figcaption a:hover {
 color: #4f5856;
 background: #fff;
}

/*.paginas img {

 width: 80%;

}

.paginas {

 position: relative;
 
}*/




.tabla {

 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}


.tercio {

 overflow: hidden;
 width: 25%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
    .tercio {
        width: 25%; 
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:970px) {
    .tercio{
        width: 50%;

    }
    
    figcaption p {

        font-size: .8em;
        padding: 5px 10px;
      }

      figcaption p a {

        font-size: .8em;
      }

      figcaption {

        height: 100%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .tercio {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="web">

        <div>

            <div class="align-center cabeceraWeb">

                <header>
             
                  <h3>algunos proyectos realizados</h3>

                  <hr>

                </header>

               

            </div>
        
            <div class="paginas">

              <ul class="tabla">
         
                  <li class="tercio">

                        <figure>

                          <img src="img/estructural/nite.jpg">

                        <figcaption>

                           <h6>Nite</h6>

                           <p>Proyecto fotografía nocturna</p>

                           <p><a href="#" target="_blank">ver en youtube</a></p>

                       </figcaption>

                        </figure>

                  </li>
      
                  <li class="tercio">

                          <figure>

                            <img src="img/estructural/oceanus.jpg">

                            <figcaption>

                             <h6>Oceanus</h6>

                           <p>Proyecto divulgación científica</p>

                           <p><a href="#" target="_blank">ver en youtube</a></p>

                        </figcaption>

                          </figure>


                   </li>                 
                

                  <li class="tercio">
                
                        <figure>

                          <img src="img/estructural/casaRural.jpg">

                          <figcaption>

                           <h6>Casa Rural</h6>

                           <p>Proyecto Casa Rural Callejón de la Gata</p>

                           <p><a href="#">ver en youtube</a></p>

                      </figcaption>

                        </figure>

                      

                  </li>

                  <li class="tercio">
            
                        <figure>

                          <img src="img/estructural/olas.jpg">

                           <figcaption>

                           <h6>Oceanus 2</h6>

                           <p>Proyecto divulgación científica</p>

                           <p><a href="#">en construcción</a></p>

                      </figcaption>

                        </figure>

                      

                  </li>
      
            </ul>

          </div>
        


      </section>
```

Comment: Seria mas facil poder ayudarte si lo pasas a un Pen de Codepen para visualizar bien el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade lo siguiente a tu css, asi el figcaption tendra el ancho de la imagen ya que el figure se adaptara a esta.

```
#web figure {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: HOla, no funciona, en vez del div tengo una imagen, aun poniendo figure>img no funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrias incluir en la pregunta tu codigo original? Sera más facil encontrar la solución.

Comment: Ya lo he subido

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta, dime si asi funciona

Comment: sí funciona!! Mil gracias!!